Extract data using rex in Splunk
I have 2 records for PaymentType as send and receive.
I would like to extract PaymentType as receive only so that I can further compare.
Could you please let me know how do I can extract PaymentType as receive only.
transaction:  {"version":1,"status":"approved","identifier":"0c4240e0-2c2c-6427-fb1f-71131029cd89","amount":"[REDACTED]","transactionAmount":"[REDACTED]","timestamp":"2024-06-13T04:29:20.673+0000","statusChangedTimestamp":"2024-06-13T04:29:56.337+0000","type":"payment","transferIdentifier":"cded3395-38f9-4258-90a5-9269abfa5536","currencyCode":"USD","PaymentType":"receive","senderHandle":"[REDACTED]","recipientHandle":"[REDACTED]","fees":[],"transferMode":"contact"}

transaction:  {"version":1,"status":"approved","identifier":"0c4240e0-2c2c-6427-fb1f-71131029cd89","amount":"[REDACTED]","transactionAmount":"[REDACTED]","timestamp":"2024-06-13T04:29:20.673+0000","statusChangedTimestamp":"2024-06-13T04:29:56.337+0000","type":"payment","transferIdentifier":"cded3395-38f9-4258-90a5-9269abfa5536","currencyCode":"USD","PaymentType":"send","senderHandle":"[REDACTED]","recipientHandle":"[REDACTED]","fees":[],"transferMode":"contact"}


You shouldn't need a rex - if you want to only find events with "PaymentType":"receive" then put that in your search directly.  You do need to escape the quotes so it would look like "\"PaymentType\":\"receive\"" in the search.  If you need a rex can you say why?
